# Mobilesubstrate: Create a tweak to hook into another tweak or dylib

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, tweak, cydia-substrate

Is it possible to create a tweak to hook into another existing tweak?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. .xm files cannot be dumped using class-dump. You could probably hook into other frameworks or other source files used by that tweak, by dumping them. The tweak to be hooked identifier should be used to load it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the tweak has some objc classes, you can always hook them. Just do that after they get loaded.